# Installing ubuntu on Lenovo Thinkpad T440s

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, thinkpad

I just received my Lenovo Thinkpad T440s. I would like to install Ubuntu on it. I would like to keep the option of using Windows through a VM on my system. Here are my questions

1. a) Lenovo did not ship me the OS discs. Is it possible for me to create a Windows installation media from the recovery partition?

   b) What are all the partitions that I can get rid off once I have a recovery media created.
2. Would the installation media created from the recovery partition help me get rid off all the bloatware installed along?
3. a) I don't see any license key for Windows unlike my Dell laptops, will I be able to install the Windows in a VM using the installation media created from the recovery partition?

   b) If I cannot install this version of Windows in a VM what would be the best way to dual boot the system using Grub (I think T440s uses UEFI)?

   c) Are there any instructions available for one to install Ubuntu or is it equally trivial like just booting of the USB drive and installing it like any normal system?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you can't create installation media from the recovery partition.
2. If you install Ubuntu and obtain Windows 7 installation media, you can use the license key that came with your ThinkPad to install that.  There is no bloatware on the official install media.
3. a) Take out the battery and look under that, or look in the documentation.

   b) Install Windows first, then Ubuntu should detect it and you'll be able to choose from both.

   c) The installer's really easy, just follow the prompts.

Comment: I looked for the license key in the battery compartment. The only sticker there is for the model and serial number. I dont find the Microsoft CoA sticker any where on the laptop.

Comment: There are a number of freeware utilities that can expose your product key on Windows.  [Here's one](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/).  Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows key on the Lenovo ThinkPad 440s is in the bios.

UEFI and secure boot can make dual booting difficult. 
Here's a great resource / how to page for the T440s
http://stephen.rees-carter.net/geek/thinkpad-t440s-ubuntu

This is also informative
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface